# Two action switch on circuit

Tags: switching, hardware

Trying to fix my electronic lawn mower and I have a switch in it that is quite interesting.

You need two actions. One is the engage the lever normally it is horizontally across the switch body when the case is properly assembled, when the lever is pressed parallel against the push bar on the mower handle it pulls the white assembly with the spring up into its body

[image: electric lawn mower switch]

Am I correct to understand that this is effective switching whatever pins 1 & 2 in common (they are joined together
in the crimp on pin 2) are connected to from pin 3 to pin 4?

Comment: Likely, 1 & 2 are both connected to the motor, and 3 is the other side of the motor, with 4 going to battery (or reverse). When pressed, that should send 36 VDC to motor, and when released, *short circuits* the motor, acting as a powerful safety brake.

Comment: 1 & 2 never connect together ... 3 & 4 never connect together ... 2 & 4 connect when the switch is in one position ... 1 & 3 connect  when the switch is in the other position

Comment: @jsotola they are wired together already that has a loop that connects both and then goes to the black wire. Wasn't something I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the schematic to help understand the switch functions.

[image]

The purpose of switching contacts '1' & '3' is to energise / de-energise the motor
and that of '2' & '4' to brake the motor, after it's de-energised.

Contacts '1' & '3' are normally open and '2' & '4' normally closed.

When the mower hand lever is actuated, contacts '2' & '4' open and '1' & '3' close to energise the motor.

When the mower hand lever is released, contacts '1' & '3' open and '2' & '4' close to de-energise and brake the motor.